# Solidworks 2017 Dowel holes misaligned

Tags: solidworks

I have following assembly:
[image: Problematic assembly]
and I have following `Dowel holes` misaligned:
[image: Problematic dowel holes]
Now, both sets of holes (for both parts) were created using `Linear Sketch Pattern` tool and now I want to mate these parts "through" these dowel holes sets. The first option is to recheck `Linear Sketch Pattern` parameters for both sets, however is it possible to automatic creation of holes at exact position from first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not fully understanding you but it seems like what you are trying to do is create the dowels and the dowel holes in the same action; this is fairly straightforward.

Presumable you used **Extruded Cut** to make these holes, what you want to do is replace that feature with an **Extruded Boss/Base** using the same sketch and be sure to uncheck the **Merge Entities** box so that the extrusion is a separate body from your main part.

You need to **Select all bodies** in the scene and create an **Intersect** feature. Once again make sure that **Merge Entities** is turned **off**.

The final step is to use **Insert>Feature>Split** to export each of the bodies in the scene as individual parts so that you can combine them in assembly.

I hope this was the answer you were looking for